# How to enable cookies while sending a request with Java Jersey client?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I need to send a get request to an API and get the results. I am using Java, Jersey library in my project and I decided to use Jersey client in order to get the data. However, the API returns an error message which indicates that I should enable cookies to reach out this API. I can get correct response when try with applications like postman, or just with using a normal browser like chrome. But I could not find out how can I enable cookies in Java Jersey client object.

I searched to learn how to enable cookies in a Java Jersey client but I could not find any resource about it. So I could not try any solution.

My code is very simple:

```
    Client client = Client.create(); // Create jerseu client
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(BASEURI +  EXCHANGEINFO); // create web resource with a specific URI

    System.out.println(webResource 
            .accept("application/json")
            .get(ClientResponse.class)
            .getEntity(String.class)); // Write results to console
```

At the result of this request, I got the error that I mentioned above. How can I enable cookies while sending a request with Java Jersey client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion, I have gone through the api you have provided. Actually, the api provides a misleading message while making rest call. If you look into the details of the error message which is received from the api call, it says.

> The owner of this website (api.pro.coinbase.com) has banned your
>   access based on your browser's signature (4e0a3c06895d89af-ua21).

So what is the answer ? The api actually wants that the call should be made from browser and each browser sends a header called "User-Agent". See what is [user agent](https://www.howtogeek.com/114937/htg-explains-whats-a-browser-user-agent/). However, I have solved your problem, you can check the complete code below.

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class TestGetCallByJersey {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String resourceUri = "https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products";
    try {
      Client client = Client.create();
      WebResource webResource = client.resource(resourceUri);
      ClientResponse response =
          webResource
              .accept("application/json")
              .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0")
              .get(ClientResponse.class);

      System.out.println("response status = " + response.getStatus());
      String result = response.getEntity(String.class);
      System.out.println("Output from api call .... \n" + result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Currently, I have tested in Java 8 and I used the following jar file.

**jersey-client version 1.8**
If you are using, Maven, you can include the following dependency in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Could you share the libraries that you used, import? Because com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client, does not have a method which returns a WebTarget object. And What I want is not adding a cookie, it is enabling cookies.

Comment: You can use jersey-client jar file, you can get it from mvnrepository.com

Comment: I still could not get any answer related with my problem. Could you please read the question again?

Comment: There is nothing called "enable cookie" in jersey client. Either you have to send cookie or you have to receive cookie. Check this link, it may be useful to you. http://ashokprajapati999.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-send-cookie-using-jersey-client.html

Comment: Just to test, clear all the cache in chrome browser, try to make a call and check what is going on in get call. You can invoke Ctrl+Shift+I in chrome browser in network request.

Comment: When I send a get request to this page "https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products" with using a browser, I get the result that I want. But when I try it with using Java Jersey client, the page returns an error message which says that "Please enable cookies". How can I solve this? Do you have any answer to this question?

Comment: I have solved you problem, check the updated answer. If you had provided the api url,I could have helped you earlier. Anyway, check and let me know whether it works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I accepted the answer, it solved my problem for this specific URI. I get a similar error in another api (https://sistemkoin.com/api/market/ticker). It again gives `The owner of this website (api.pro.coinbase.com) has banned your access based on your browser's signature ...` error. This time adding user-agent did not worked. It returns some long javascript codes. Can you try this with the new URI that I provided please?

Comment: Thank you. Try accordingly.Please create a new question with more details about the api so that others can see and may find it useful and they may help you.